# Nexus 5 monospace font has different width for unicode circles

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, font-size

On an Android app, I have credit-card entry as four EditText fields. The fields are configured to use a monospace typeface.

When I type numbers, the width of each 4-character block is always the same is expected.

However, to mask credit card details that have already been entered I use a unicode black circle character "●". It turns out that even with a monospace typeface the width of "●●●●" is wider than "1111"! Which is causing me problems when I'm trying to support different system font sizes and screen sizes.

[image: Monospaced circle vs numbers]

Interestingly, on Nexus 5 with Marshmallow, or Samsung phones on KitKat, I don't see this issue!

Am I missing something or is the default Android monospace font on Lollipop not actually monospaced?

My XML:

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_number_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/card_field_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="●●●●"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:maxLength="4">
        </EditText>

        ...
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've noticed similar problems on Marshmallow, the line drawing characters are not monospaced. This shows up mostly when I use Connectbot and run a terminal session using these characters; boxes and columns don't line up with the text. This makes some screens unusable; I may downgrade back to KitKat.

Comment: On my Droid4 running KitKat, there's no problem. On my Nook HD+ running CyanogenMod 13 (Marshmallow) monospace isn't right. I also checked on my Geekbox running Lollipop, same problem there. I also tried loading older versions of DroidSansMono.ttf onto my Nook (from the Android source tree https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/data/fonts ) but even using the KitKat version of the font didn't change anything. It seems that some other font is being used instead of DroidSansMono.ttf. What does /system/etc/fonts.xml look like on your Nexus 5?

Comment: I found that in KitKat the line drawing characters came from DroidSansFallback.ttf - this file is completely absent on my Marshmallow build. Also, those characters are missing from the latest version of DroidSansFallback on github. Some other font from the Noto* family is being used for these characters instead. If I hide all of the Noto* fonts and install the KitKat DroidSansFallback.ttf then I get properly lined up line drawing characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Marshmallow build these graphics characters are coming from NotoSansSymbols-Regular-Subsetted.ttf and they're definitely not monospaced. Google screwed this up. Hiding that file and using DroidSansFallback.ttf from Kitkat makes things line up for me.

I've submitted a bug report here https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts/issues/617